# Codeigniter insert_batch error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, sqlite, insert

I use Codeigniter v2.1.4 to insert some values in a sqlite3 database.

The problem is that when I try to insert a batch it gives me an error:

```
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a >non-object in E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_driver.php >on line 193
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\index.php:0
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   2. require_once() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\index.php:202
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   3. call_user_func_array() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:359
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   4. Main_controller->index() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:359
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   5. Favorites_Model->addToTemp() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\application\controllers\main_controller.php:7
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   6. CI_DB_driver->query() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\application\models\favorites_model.php:106
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   7. CI_DB_driver->simple_query() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\system\database\DB_driver.php:299
>[17-Jan-2014 22:44:17 UTC] PHP   8. CI_DB_pdo_driver->_execute() E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\system\database\DB_driver.php:453
```

If I insert only one row it works ok.

This is the problematic query:

```
INSERT INTO temp (Date, Name)
   Values("test","test2"),("test","test2"),("test","test2");
```

If I use this:

```
INSERT INTO temp (Date, Name) Values("test","test2");
```

it works ok.

Also if I use `db->insert(tablename, values)` it works ok, but if I use `db->insert_batch(tablename, array)`, I get the same error mentioned above.

In a separate sqlite browser i can execute the above querys on the same database without any problem.

Here is my database config in Codeigniter:

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'db/Support_Mails.db';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';//APPPATH.'db/Support_Mails.db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = APPPATH.'cache';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

This is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [temp] (
    [Date] [TEXT(255)], 
    [Name] [TEXT(255)], 
    [Mail] [TEXT(255)], 
    [Subject] [TEXT(255)], 
    [Conversation] [TEXT(255)], 
    [Language] [TEXT(255)], 
    [Body] [TEXT(30000)], 
    [ROWID] [TEXT(255)], 
    [TableName] [TEXT(255)], 
    [userid] [TEXT(255)]);
```

the array after using print_r(array) looks like this:

```
[18-Jan-2014 10:20:04 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => test
            [Name] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => test
            [Name] => test
        )
)
```

Any idea why it does that?
(Somehow i think that there is a problem in the Codeigniter setup, not in the query itself because i used the same query on the same database with an sqlite browser and it works ok)

Comment: would you please show your array content?

Answer (score 2):

i have posted it on github as a CodeIgniter 2.1.4 issue and as i found out,"SQLite3 is not supported by CI 2.1.4 and the PDO driver in 2.1.x is experimental, which means that errors are expected.Full SQLite3 support via the 'sqlite3' and 'pdo/sqlite' drivers is available in 3.0-dev"
- https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/2834#issuecomment-32838494

Answer (score 0):

Because of

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in E:\Repository\cashy-support-app2\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_driver.php on line 193.

I am going to guess that your array does not hold the keys for the columns in the database.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

It is hard to pin-point the exact problem without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because sqlite doesn't support this kind of query, not sure if codeigniter handled this issue or not.